# Items not adding to combobox VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am using Excel VBA to place strings from another sheet's row of cells into a combobox dropdown. When a user types into the combobox, the dropdown should be filtering results to only results that contain the same character(s) as typed in the combobox. However, I cannot get the code to make this behavior happen. The code only seems to grab the first character from each string in the data sheet and not match a character at any position of any string.

When the workbook is open:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
InitnewCmb
End Sub
```

newMdl:

This part all works:

```
Public newCol As Collection
Public indNewCol As Long
Public lastColumn As Long

Public newCargoNum As Long



Public Sub InitnewCmb()
'Initialize combobox
lastColumn = Database.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    Set newCol = New Collection
    newCargoNum = 0
    With newCol
        For indNewCol = 2 To lastColumn

            .Add Database.Cells(2, indNewCol).Value
        'Take the value of each cell, a string and add to the collection of strings

        newCargoNum = newCargoNum + 1

        Next indNewCol

    End With
```

Here's where things get out of hand. FilternewCmb is called now inside InitnewCmb

```
FilternewCmb ""


End Sub

Public Sub FilternewCmb(newFilter As String)
Dim l As Long




    For l = 1 To newCargoNum


        If InStr(1, newCol.Item(l), newFilter, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            'If entered character matches a character in any string in collection
            Tool.newCmb.AddItem newCol.Item(l)


            'keep these strings in dropdown
        End If

    Next l

End Sub
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction on why the filtering is not working? Finally, once an item is selected in the dropdown, I want that item to populate the combobox and have the dropdown disappear too, which should be easy.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the variable newFilter is always "". This will cause InStr to always return Null. Is that the functionality you're after?

Comment: When the workbook opens, I want the combobox to be clear. However, when the user starts typing in it for the first time, I want the filtering to run using the text the user has typed into the combobox. The initializing function I want to run only when the workbook opens, but the filtering should be continuous as the user types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setup will filter a ComboBox drop-down list as you type

Create a new ComboBox on Sheet1 (ActiveX Control), as in the image bellow, named "ComboBox1"

Add this code to Sheet1 VBA module:

```
Option Explicit

Private cLst As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange1(ByVal Target As Range)
    cLst = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1)
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = cLst
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    filterComboList Sheet1.ComboBox1, cLst
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()   'or _MouseDown()
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub

Public Sub filterComboList(ByRef cmb As ComboBox, ByRef dLst As Variant)
    Dim itm As Variant, lst As String, sel As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With cmb
        sel = .Value
        If IsEmpty(cLst) Then cLst = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1)
        For Each itm In cLst
            If Len(itm) > 0 Then If InStr(1, itm, sel, 1) Then lst = lst & itm & "||"
        Next
        If Len(lst) > 0 Then .List = Split(Left(lst, Len(lst) - 2), "||") Else .List = dLst
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

[image: Sheet1 Setup]

Change cell selection on Sheet1 to refresh the drop-down list

Comment: Thanks Paul. How do I make the dropdown list/items appear automatically when typing, instead of having to click the dropdown arrow to show the options?

Comment: I updated the answer with a new Sub: ComboBox1_KeyPress() - you'll see the drop-down as soon as you start typing, and GotFocus() - as soon as you click it

Comment: Thanks again. A few more things (I am quite new to VBA). I would like the boxes to not be case sensitive (should I just use the vbTextCompare in InStr?) Also, I would like to exclude blank cells that appear in my rows/columns. I made two comboboxes, one that runs through a row on the sheet and one a column.

Comment: Also, the dropdown is breaking apart strings containing commas. "1,2 BENZENE DICARBOXYLIC ACID, BENZYL BUTYL ESTER" gets broken into items "1" "2 BENZENE DICARBOXYLIC ACID" and " BENZYL BUTYL ESTER" because of the delimiting behavior after the InStr lines of the code.

Comment: I updated it to address all items you mentioned. Make sure to update _Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1)_ in 2 places, to whatever range you need to use

Comment: Thank you, everything seems to be running smoothly now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I know it has been a while but I just revisited this code. There's an issue where as soon as the user hits the arrow down on the dropdown list of entries, the combobox populates with the first dropdown item and all of the other items in the dropdown disappear, because it then tries to filter the dropdown by the item in the combobox, which is an exact match for one item in the dropdown (the one that was highlighted upon arrow down). Anyways to stop this behavior?